# why list index out of range but it seems ok

Tags: python-3.x

Why did I get "list index out of range"
when I was trying to run this code

```
x = 20
l = [[] for i in range(0, x)]
for m in range(x):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i != len(l):
            l[i+1].append(m)
```

Comment: shouldn't  ```if i != len(l):``` fix this problem?

Comment: ok I guess I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in range(len(l)):` produces `0` to `len(l) - 1` inclusive. So `i` is never equal to `len(l)`, but when it's equal to `len(l) - 1`, `l[i + 1]` is trying to access `l[len(l)]` which is one more than the highest legal index in `l` (a `list`'s indices run from `0` (inclusive) to its length (exclusive), so the length itself is never a valid index).

Your test should be `if i != len(l) - 1:` to exclude the case where `i + 1` isn't a legal index. Or more simply (and much more efficiently), just limit the `range` in the first place so you don't need to add `1` and directly skip index `0` as your current code does:

```
for m in range(x):
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        l[i].append(m)
```

Mind you, in this specific circumstance, you could just build the final `l` with:

```
l = [[]] + [list(range(20)) for _ in range(1, x)]
```

or without the possibly overly dense listcomp:

```
l = [[]]
for _ in range(1, x):
    l.append(list(range(20)))
```

since that's what your code is doing in a somewhat circuitous way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address the reason that this:

```py
if i != len(l):
```

doesn't work.

I'll skip ahead through the loop until we get to `m=0` and `i=19`.

```py
for m in range(x): # m=0 (still on the first loop)
    for i in range(len(l)): # i=19 (the highest index it will reach)
        ...
```

The line

```py
if i != len(l):
```

Says: "As long as the current value for `i` *is not* 20 (the initial length of the list), then the following code is safe to run".

But what happens when `i=19`?

The if statement will check if `i` (19) doesn't equal 20, and since that check is successful the next line of code will then run:

```py
l[i+1].append(m)
```

With `i=19`, this will then do the following:

```py
l[i+1].append(m)
# then
l[19+1].append(m)
# then
l[20].append(m)
# then
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Since 20 is *outside* of the list's range. The list's indexes only go from `0` to `19`!

That is why your check doesn't work.